# JPA @Converter vs @ReadTransformer / @WriteTransformer

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

What is de difference between JPA @Converter and @ReadTransformer / @WriteTransformer.
It seems both are used for the same pourpouse: transform between the db representation and de model object representation.

Answer (score 1):

They are similar, the main difference is that @Converter can only be used for a single column, where as @Transformation can write to multiple columns.

In general I would recommend using @Converter, unless the mapping requires multiple columns.